# How to Save the Checkmark Accessory in A Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to develop a checklist app and have been stuck for a while trying to save the state of a checkmark. When I go off the tableView and back on all of the saved checkmarks are erased. I have imported UKIT then defined the class.

Here is my code:

```
var PreDefinedTasks = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
        if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return PreDefinedTasks.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "List1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = PreDefinedTasks[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

I have looked into NSCoder as a solution but cant seem to get it to work properly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can keep a list array for the checked and unchecked items and set cell.assessoryType according to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it, if you follow the whole solution, it will save even when the app closes.

Make an array off type Bool like this: `var checkmarks = [Int : Bool]()`

Then, in cellForRow function, add this:

```
if checkmarks[indexPath.row] != nil {
    cell.accessoryType = checkmarks[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none
} else {
    checkmarks[indexPath.row] = false
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

And in the didSelectRow function, add this:

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
    if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
        checkmarks[indexPath.row] = false
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        checkmarks[indexPath.row] = true
    }
}
```

If you want it to save when the app closes, you have to save the checkmarks array in UserDefaults by doing this:

In didSelectRow function, at the bottom after everything add this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: checkmarks), forKey: "checkmarks")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Then also, in viewDidLoad, add this:

```
if let checks = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "checkmarks") as? NSData {
    checkmarks = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: checks as Data) as! [Int : Bool]
}
```

Let me know if this answer helped and if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**
So what I completely forgot about is that [Int : Bool] is not an NSDictionary, it is just a Dictionary. UserDefaults can't store Dictionary objects, only NSDictionary which is why you have to change it to NSData so it is able to save the [Int : Bool]. Hope it works this time :)

Comment: thanks, that did help me understand data persistence in more depth. how could i change this to keep the data even if the app closes? again, thanks for the reply :) edit: i couldnt see the rest of your answer sorry. i hate imacs :(

Comment: I worded it weirdly but the last part of my answer shows how to save it when the app closes

Comment: yeah sorry about that. you worded it fine, very concise. thanks for the help

Comment: it now says "comparing non-optional values of type bool to nil always returns true" and crashes whenever I load up the table view :(

Comment: let me take a look at this, ill be back in a minute

Comment: i tried that and then Attempt to set a non-property-list object appeared and the app now crashes in a different place

Comment: This is great stuff! I have one question though:

I'm looking to only keep one checkmark per cell, ie to remove the previous checkmark in the didDeselectRowAt method which works fine, except for when I relaunch the app. 

After relaunch there is the new checkmark and the old one, until I tap the cell for the old checkmark (from the previous launch) and then make the new selection. 

Any thoughts on how to only keep one checkmark, even if the user relaunches the app and wants to make a new selection?

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Sorry for such a long comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the indexpath in your array based on checkmark selected on your tableView rows.

Comment: could you suggest how I would go about that? thanks for the reply :)

Comment: So inside your didSelectRow delegate method you can get the indexpath of which rows you have been selected right. That you can store in array and when you reload your table on that time check indexpath if matched set the checkmark on cell.

Answer (score 0):

As per you implementation, the UITableViewCell is getting reused with identifier as "List1". So if you want to re-use the cell then you have to keep updating the correct accessoryType by storing the state against the predefines tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Since cells get unloaded and later reused, you'll need to store the state of the checkmark elsewhere. In this example in an array called `preDefinedTaskCheckmarkState`. When loading the cells you'll also need to set the checkmark state.

```
var PreDefinedTasks = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var preDefinedTaskCheckmarkState = [Bool](repeating: false, count: 4)

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {

        preDefinedTaskCheckmarkState[indexPath.row] = !(cell.accessoryType == .checkmark)

        cell.accessoryType = preDefinedTaskCheckmarkState[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return PreDefinedTasks.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "List1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = PreDefinedTasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = preDefinedTaskCheckmarkState[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell
}
```

Comment: that was a method that i didn't consider. thank you for the reply that was useful :)